# php calendar script

Tags: php, calendar

Does anyone know of a rudimentary PHP script that will take data from a list of events (like something output from a CMS) and display them in a html table calendar?

I don't need an js or ajax, just the server side code.

Comment: Off-topic: seeking off-site resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I need here

[php calendar script](http://davidwalsh.name/php-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

I think [easyphpcalendar](http://www.easyphpcalendar.com/) might be what you need.

Comment: looks like some nice software, but ideally, I would like to feed the calendar some data and have it only display that data in an html table calendar

this one looks like it's a full scale calendar with a back end admin and lots of features

Comment: What exactly do you want, then? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

[Php-Calendar](http://www.php-calendar.com/) Works for me.